# Armazenar valores num vetor em ordem invertida

Tags: java, array

O objetivo é o seguinte: ler 10 valores de um determinado vetor, depois disso, criar outro vetor, que tenha os mesmos valores do primeiro vetor, porém em ordem invertida, por exemplo, o primeiro valor do 1º vetor é o décimo do 2º vetor, o segundo valor do 1º vetor é o penúltimo do 2º vetor, e assim sucessivamente. Tentei fazer porém o segundo vetor sempre tem o valor de 0. Sei que tenho que usar um `for` para isso, porém não sei se utilizei da maneira correta.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] firstArray = new int [10];
    int [] secondArray = new int [10];

    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        firstArray[i] =(int)Math.round(Math.random()*50); //Gerando valores aleatórios
    }

    //Passando valores
    for (int i = 9; i <= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++) {
            secondArray[j] = firstArray[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    //Apresentar valores
    System.out.println("\nPrimeiro Array:");
    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(firstArray[i]+"; ");
    }

    System.out.println("\nSegundo Array:");
    for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(secondArray[i]+"; ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Isto não faz sentido mesmo. Coloque o resto do código.

Comment: @bigown Fiz algumas alterações, veja se consegue me ajudar :)

Comment: Não seria melhor colocar o código que está fazendo ao invés de postar trechos soltos?

Comment: @bigown Coloquei, mas acho que não mudou muita coisa ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como só vai mexer em um *array*, só precisa de um laço. Para achar o elemento do outro *array* basta usar matemática. É só calcular o índice ao contrário. Poderia varrer o *array* do primeiro para o último que a fórmula funciona igual. A fórmula de inversão dos elementos é universal. Além disso havia um sinal errado no primeiro laço impedindo a execução dele. O correto seria:

```
for (int i = firstArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    secondArray[secondArray.length - i - 1] = firstArray[i];
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/trm3kg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mignszva-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Inverted.java).

Idealmente deveria ter uma constante com o tamanho do *array* para ser usado em ambos, assim garantiria que ambos tem o mesmo tamanho. Não afeta em nada o código, mas dá mais semântica ao que se deseja. Do jeito que está, se alguém mexer no código, pode sem querer criar problemas.

Se existisse necessidade de dois laços, não poderia ser da forma usada, o `break` estava encerrando o laço na primeira passagem, portanto o laço não ocorria de fato.

Comment: Nem tinha pensado nessa possibilidade, valeu cara. Na verdade dava para fazer essa ação no laço onde é atribuído os valores do primeiro vetor mesmo, sem necessidade de um segundo `for`.

Comment: @DanielSantos sim, dava, eu não fiz porque achei que era requisito do exercício. Data até pra já imprimir os dados do primeiro. O código só precisava de 2 laços.